# Using single power source for an Arduino and a relay

Tags: power-supply, arduino, relay

I'm trying to find a way to build a device that turns on/off a specific machine when a message (SMS) is received.

I sorted the SMS and relay part. However, the issue I'm having is that I'm now connecting the Arduino to a different source than the relay (eg: wall wart, which seems to generate a lot of heat by the way).

What I need to do is put everything in a box and have single IN and OUT cables with no additional wiring or different connections outside the box. It also needs to stay up 24/7.

Can I please ask what is the best approach to handle this? Without using batteries or external power sources for the Arduino, only the same cable that is used for the relay.

Comment: Optocouplers may suite. Also transferring signal some distance use current loop and twisted pairs.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the actual problem is. If you've chosen a relay with a coil voltage to match whatever supply is running your Arduino, then connect the relay (and whatever switching circuit have have between the Arduino & the relay) to that power supply - job done ...

Comment: If your wall wart is putting out a distressing amount of heat, something may be wrong.  Also, if your relay is not going to be preferentially in one state (e.g. load on all the time except for short times when it's off) it might make sense to look for a latching relay.

Comment: What I'm trying to create is an SMS switch with a single input and single output. At the moment, I'm feeding the Arduino 5V and have the relay linked to 220V. I'd like to use the same 220V to power the Arduino as well.